# Hibernate @Where is not enforcing at @MappedSuperClass Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, where-clause

For migrating from eclipse link to hibernate, I am looking for the equivalent of eclipse link annotation `@AdditionalCriteria` in Hibernate at `@MappedSupperClass` `BaseEntity` level, to filter logically deleted records from all entities extending this `BaseEntity`.

I had found `@Where` annotation. But, this only works at `Entity` level and not at BaseEntity. Please let me know if there is any possibility to add this or any other Hibernate annotation to filter `BaseEntity`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Where(clause = "DEL_IND = 0")  // DOES NOT WORK
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "DEL_IND")
    private boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;

    public boolean getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted() {
        this.deleted = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Where(clause = "DEL_IND = 0")  // THIS WORKS BUT NEEDS TO BE REPEATED IN ALL ENTITIES
public class Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    --------------------
    getters & setters
    --------------------
    --------------------
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open a Hibernate JIRA issue for this. The only workaround is to manually add the `@Where` annotation to all your entities or use filters.

With filters you have the option of dynamically enable/disable them, which is useful since you might want to fetch a deleted item sometimes.